# Target class [App\Repositories\User\UserRepository] does not exist

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel and try to integrate the repository in laravel. 
follow this link [https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-repository-pattern-tutorial-from-scratchexample.html.](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-repository-pattern-tutorial-from-scratchexample.html)

but getting the below issue. don't know what's wrong with code. try to find a solution but not getting any particular solution.

UserInterface

```
namespace App\Repositories\User;


interface UserInterface {


    public function getAll();


    public function find($id);


    public function delete($id);
}
```

UserRepoServiceProvide

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class UserRepoServiceProvide extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

    }


    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Repositories\User\UserInterface', 'App\Repositories\User\UserRepository');
    }
```

UserRepository

```
use App\Repositories\User\UserInterface as UserInterface;
use App\User;


class UserRepository implements UserInterface
{
    public $user;


    function __construct(User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }


    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->user->getAll();
    }


    public function find($id)
    {
        return $this->user->findUser($id);
    }


    public function delete($id)
    {
        return $this->user->deleteUser($id);
    }
}
```

User Model

```
   public function getAll()
    {
        return static::all();
    }


    public function findUser($id)
    {
        return static::find($id);
    }


    public function deleteUser($id)
    {
        return static::find($id)->delete();
    }
```

UserController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Web;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Repositories\User\UserInterface as UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $users = $this->user->getAll();
        return view('users.index',['users']);
    }

}
```

composer.json

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "App\\Repositories\\": "app/Repositories/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
```

but still getting this issue

[image]

Please Help.

folder path
[image]

Comment: You can remove  the `App\\Repositories\\": "app/Repositories/` (as well as the comma from the line above it) from your composer file and run `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 0):

In your *UserController* :
remove

```
use App\Repositories\User\UserInterface as UserInterface;
```

and add

```
use App\Repositories\User\UserRepository as UserInterface;
```